# Redirect non-www to www on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, ssl, redirect, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application deployed on the Python 3 stack for ElasticBeanstalk with Apache.

DNS is handled through Cloudflare because I'm using an SSL certificate from them. I have a single page rule of `http://*.example.com/$
Always use HTTPS`.

I have an https-instance config file:

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod24_ssl : []

files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
      WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
      WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
      WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"



        Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/example/static/
        <Directory /opt/python/current/app/example/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/application.py

        <Directory /opt/python/current/app>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi-ssl processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
          python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages \
      home=/opt/python/current/app \
      user=wsgi \
      group=wsgi
        WSGIProcessGroup wsgi-ssl

      </VirtualHost>

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      stuff
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      stuff
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

container_commands:
  01killhttpd:
    command: "killall httpd"
  02waitforhttpddeath:
command: "sleep 3"
```

SSL works. I can do a DNS redirect in Route53, but then it won't let me use the Cloudflare certificate anymore.

I've tried looking at resources like this: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-perform-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare- but not very clear to me...

I want example.com and any path that follows example.com to redirect permanently to https://www.example.com/{path}. And I want http://www.example.com and any path that follows to redirect to https://www.example.com/{path}.

Comment: Anything on this yet?